# Using module "child_process" without Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, postmark

I'm using Webpack to bundle dependencies, one of which is the emailing service `postmark`.  This service depends upon something called `child_process` that apparently ships with node.

The problem is, when I attempt to run webpack to bundle my app, it complains:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in ...

Most of the answers online say that, in response to this error, I should add the line:

```
  node: {
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
```

to my webpack config.  But this makes no sense, because then webpack just doesn't try to look for child_process, and consequently, when I run my app, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: exec is not a function

which is an error from `postmark` (the service that relies upon `child_process`) complaining that the `exec` function within the `child_process` module doesn't exist.

Thus, I'm wondering how I can include the `child_process` module in my build without webpack complaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Front-end developer of Postmark here.

It looks like you're trying to bundle `postmark.js` into your client-side JavaScript but https://github.com/wildbit/postmark.js is a Node.js library. This means it will not run in the browser and requires a running Node.js server.

The main reason for not supporting browser environment is security. As you can see in this example:

```
var postmark = require("postmark");
var client = new postmark.Client("<server key>");
```

it requires you to insert the auth token. Bundling this with your client-side JS would expose it and allow everyone access your postmark account API.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks for the response- I ported it over to my express backend and it's working great.