# Node modules undefined in my webpack bundled script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify

I am making a web app which, based on a jped picture, recognizes characters and renders it in an interactive interface for the user - this includes some async code. There are 4 js scripts file, which all require npm modules, and an html view.

In order to test the app client-side, I have decided to bundle the scripts together.
It shows the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

List of my npm modules whose code returns this error at run time:

- isexe: requires [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)
- destroy: fs
- tesseractocr: [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), fs

I have tried:

1. [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) my scripts into a bundle, but I read that it would not work with async functions ;
2. [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) the scripts into a bundle, but Node modules like fs and [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) are returning 'undefined' ;
3. adding a specific Node module, [child-process-ctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-ctor), to force child_process to the included

Alas, the same error message is returned.

Questions:

1. Is bundling the scripts the right approach?
2. Is the problem that webpack does not transpile fs and child_process [correctly](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser#readme)?
3. Which possible solutions should I consider?

Thanks all. This is my 1st question on SO -- any feedback is much welcome!

PS: This might be redundant with [Using module "child_process" without Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983446/using-module-child-process-without-webpack?rq=1).

Comment: I'm assuming when you say you want to run node.js "client-side", you mean you want to have a more clean front end package for clients vs exposing all your development scripts. Is that correct?  If so have you looked into node-webpack libraries like this one: https://github.com/shakacode/node-webpack-async-example

Comment: @YAHsaves : I might be misexplaining myself. When I say I want to run node.js "client-side", I mean that my app is meant to be used serverless, all from the browser or client's side. I am solely using node for the npm modules (inc;. tesseractocr). I just read your link. Would your node-webpack-async-example help using externals modules and Node modules (fs, child_process) in my app? Thanks!!

Comment: @emond if you want to run your script in the browser node.js modules will not work. Node js modules require a node.js runtime. So in order for it to work "client side" your client would need to have node.js installed and they would need to run your script from the node command line (or any other similar mechanism).

Comment: @YAHsaves wow this is a realization. I thought that Node.js modules are designed to be run on the server... but naively thought browserify/webpack bundlers would create "static assets" which could then be run on the client side without the need for a Node.js runtime env. Clearly I had misunderstood this. So if my app is to run solely on the client side, I should not make use of Node.js _in the first place_, right?

Comment: You are correct to say node.js can run on the server. That's because the server will have node.js and all it's dependencies installed. However when node.js is used on a server it basically becomes php. It's a back-end processing script that makes the server output website files. It's easy to confuse "node javascript" with "browser compatible" javascript because they are both "javascript", but node modules are what set node apart from regular javascript and need node to run. So if you want to run this truly client side you need to find alternatives to node.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YAHsaves. If I want to implement it as an iPhone app, I suppose I will run into similar issues if I try to bundle Node modules, even into a Cordova app? -- maybe I should start a new thread/question for this..

Comment: yes agreed to prevent dragging this out too long this will be my last response here. However to answer your question, you have a bit more flexibility with an app because you can bundle node in your app. It's not something I would recommend doing as it will greatly increase app file-size. Also when working in a hybrid environment most of nodes features can be replaced with native code, so you may want to learn the basics of some new languages and see where that takes you.

Comment: Thanks a mil! @YAHsaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this answer is a follow up to my comments, which answer the question more directly. However here I'll go into more detail than is probably necessary, but it will thoroughly answer what you asked. Plus it's educational and I'd say it's pretty fun once you start really digging into it :D

To start at the beginning. As the internet in its early days became more advanced the need for a type of "front end logic" increased and Netscape's response to this demand was to birth a competitive, cutting edge programming language in record time.

And by record time I mean 10 days, and by competitive I mean barely functional.

That's right Javascript was born in 10 days ([literally](https://www.checkmarx.com/2018/02/12/history-javascript-infographic/)). As you can imagine it was a pretty poor language, but it worked well enough that people started using it.

Because it was the programming language of the internet, and because of how fast the internet grew, enough people started to use it that the thought of removing it became scary.

If you changed it you would destroy backward compatibility with millions of websites. The other idea would be to keep it, but also implement a new standard. However it would be hard to justify this because javascript already took a lot of work to upkeep, upkeeping multiple standards would be a nightmare (cough... [flash](https://www.techradar.com/news/internet/the-long-and-painful-death-of-flash-1324425) cough).

Javascipt was easy enough for "new" programmers to learn, but the problem was javascript's only 1 language in a world where php, ruby, mySql, Mongo, Css, Html all rule as dominant kings in their respective kingdoms.

So [someone](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&source=hp&ei=UrcLW6iQAZ-gjwTVnpCIBw&q=who%20made%20node.js&oq=who%20made%20node.js&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.252.2092.0.2140.16.8.0.0.0.0.469.1280.3-1j2.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..13.3.1278...0i131k1.0.JnF0MJm1KFU) thought it was a good idea to move javascript to the server and thus node.js was born.

However for javascript to mean anything on the server it had to be able to do things that you wouldn't want it to be able to do in your browser. For example, scan your hard drive and edit your files.

If every website you visit could start scanning and uploading everything in your system [well....](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&source=hp&ei=ZrsLW_7PK4uwjwTqhLvwDg&q=big%20brothers%20watching&oq=big%20brothers%20watching&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1l3.227.2504.0.2607.21.9.0.0.0.0.389.1117.0j1j1j2.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..17.4.1116...0i131k1.0.dDMmAd0Y4pI)

However if your server software can't edit or read files you need it to [well....](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20piece%20of%20junk)

You get the idea. It's the same language, but because of security issues node.js has some differences. Mainly the modules it's allowed to use.

Now for the fun part. Can you run node.js client side in a browser. Technically yes. In fact now that we're dumping entire [operating systems](https://win95.ajf.me/) into a subset of javascript called [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) there really isn't anything javascript can't do with enough processing power.

However even if you dump the entire node.js engine (which is basically a stripped down version of chrome) into asm.js you would still have the same security limitations placed by the "Host" browser and so your modules could only run within the sandbox the browser provides.

So it is technically just a browser within another browser Running at half the speed with the same security limitations.

Is it something I would recommend doing? Of course not.

Is it something that people haven't already tried before? Of course not.

So I hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: This helps and this goes nicely beyond my question: to be frank this is exactly what I needed to read without knowing what/how to ask. Thanks again @YAHsaves! My approach to the problem was wrong -- I could have wasted a lot more time hadn't you helped me :-)